# How to load iframe exactly one time if onload is present?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying online on the fly when page reloads based on the userid. For that I am doing

```
<body>
  <iframe frameBorder="0" id="res" src="" height="500" width="500" onload="doit()"></iframe>
</body>

<script>
    function doit(){
        var t = location.search.split('=')[1];  // get userid from the current page 
        document.getElementById('res').src="./profile/?id="+t;
    }
</script>
```

but the problem is it will keep recursive querying the `/profille/?id={id}` due to onload . I need to fire onload exactly one time after body is loaded. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Add flag to save loading state

```
<script>
var loaded = false;
function doit(){
    if (loaded) return;
    var t = location.search.split('=')[1];  // get userid from the current page 
    document.getElementById('res').src="./profile/?id="+t;
    loaded = true;
}
</script>
```